# Define array inside template for handlebars/ember?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I have a handlebars template in an ember application. It accepts an array. I currently declare the array like this

template:

```
  {{Gd-radio-input content=radioContent value="blue"}}
```

Javascript:

```
App.IndexController = Em.Controller.extend({
    radioContent: [
        {label: 'Red', value: 'red'},
        {label: 'Blue', value: 'blue'},
        {label: 'Green', value: 'green'},
        {label: 'Yellow', value: 'yellow'},
  ]
});
```

For my purposes, I would like to define the array inside the template sometimes.

I tried this, but javascrip hates me:

```
  {{Gd-radio-input content="[
    {label: 'Red', value: 'red'},
    {label: 'Blue', value: 'blue'},
    {label: 'Green', value: 'green'},
    {label: 'Yellow', value: 'yellow'},
  ]" value="blue"}}
```

Errors:

```
Assertion failed: The value that #each loops over must be an Array. You passed [
        {label: 'Red', value: 'red'},
        {label: 'Blue', value: 'blue'},
        {label: 'Green', value: 'green'},
        {label: 'Yellow', value: 'yellow'},
      ] 

Uncaught TypeError: Object [
        {label: 'Red', value: 'red'},
        {label: 'Blue', value: 'blue'},
        {label: 'Green', value: 'green'},
        {label: 'Yellow', value: 'yellow'},
      ] has no method 'addArrayObserver'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't javascript that hates you, it's handlebars/helper.  When you bind the content using the inline `string` it doesn't convert it to an array for you.

You could add some sort of contentString value that would convert it back from a string to an array and set it on the content.

```
{{Gd-radio-input contentString="[
    {label: 'Red', value: 'red'},
    {label: 'Blue', value: 'blue'},
    {label: 'Green', value: 'green'},
    {label: 'Yellow', value: 'yellow'},
  ]" value="blue"}}


GdRadioInput = Em.Componenet.extend({
  watchContentString: function(){
    var cs = this.get('contentString');
    if(cs){
      this.set('content', eval(cs));
    } 
  }.on('init')
});
```

*Note, I'm not really recommending using eval, I'm just lazy.

Comment: I can't get the watch to trigger, is there any documentation on it somewhere?

Comment: watch will only trigger on init, is it never triggering?

Comment: This works, though it's missing some stuff. Th first line needs to be App.GdRadioInputComponent = Em.Component.extend({

Answer (score 2):

You can generate a helper with `ember g helper arr` and then put this code:

```
{{Gd-radio-input content=(arr
    (hash label='Red' value='red')
    (hash label='Blue' value='blue')
    (hash label='Green' value='green')
    (hash label='Yellow' value='yellow')
  ) value="blue"}}
```

Explanation: the default helper already returns an array of the parameters. The `hash` helper generates the objects. I think the `arr` helper should already be in the default Template Helpers, BTW.

p.s.: Thanks to @locks on slack channel