# How can I pass an array property to an Ember component?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

My Ember component looks like this:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  users: undefined,
  primaryAction: 'follow',
  leftSubDetails:  [],
  rightSubDetails:  [],

  onInitialization: function(){
    console.log('this', this);
    console.log('right',this.rightSubDetails);
    console.log('rightdetail', this.get('rightSubDetails'));
  }.on("init")
});
```

And the component is called like this:

```
{{#view-users
  users=model
  primaryAction='follow'
  leftSubDetails=['tweets', 'followers', 'following']
  rightSubDetails=['follow', 'reply', 'addList']
}}
{{/view-users}}
```

Looks like nothing is printed nor can I use anything in the view. Is something wrong?

Comment: It should be `users` not `user` in the component, no? http://emberjs.jsbin.com/vuqija/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Oh yes it is users.. corrected it.. Although that does not solve this problem.

Comment: You should add those properties to the container controller and pass them to the component

Comment: Can you duplicate your issue in the jsbin I posted above in the comments?

Comment: Console statements gives 'undefined'
@KalmanHazins
http://emberjs.jsbin.com/rozatekatu/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: @Ungue Didnt get you

Comment: @KalmanHazins implemented what I meant in the post below

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It works if you declare it as a property on your controller as in:

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  details: ['follow', 'reply', 'addList']
});
```

And then:

```
{{#view-users
    users=model
    primaryAction='follow'
    leftSubDetails=['tweets', 'followers', 'following']
    rightSubDetails=details
}}
{{/view-users}}
```

In the result above `leftSubDetails` *does not work*. It will result in `undefined`.

Working demo [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/cekali/1/edit?html,js,console,output)

Comment: Ideally I would want my component to be independent. Nevertheless this works.

Comment: I think it's important to mention, that the example with `leftSubDetails` does _not_ work. It will result in `undefined`.

Answer (score 5):

Or you can check [ember-composable-helpers](https://github.com/DockYard/ember-composable-helpers)

```
{{#view-users
  users=model
  primaryAction='follow'
  leftSubDetails=(w 'tweets' 'followers' 'following')
  rightSubDetails=(w 'follow' 'reply' 'addList')
}}
{{/view-users}}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Use addon ember-composable-helpers

**ember-composable-helpers** has an **array** defined (and lot's of others too!). Look at the documentation: https://github.com/DockYard/ember-composable-helpers#array

## Custom helper

You can also define a generic helper for creating via `.hbs` files.
Run command

```
$ ember g helper arr
```

And then the hbs call would be:

```
{{#view-users
  users=model
  primaryAction='follow'
  leftSubDetails=(arr 'tweets' 'followers' 'following')
  rightSubDetails=(arr 'follow' 'reply' 'addList')
}}
{{/view-users}}
```

Reference: [Define array inside template for handlebars/ember?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20327796/define-array-inside-template-for-handlebars-ember/41743760#41743760)

Answer (score 0):

You can also pass the component a JSON string and then use JSON.parse() in your logic. Sort of cheating but prevents adding additional logic

```
{{#view-users
     users=model
     primaryAction='follow'
     leftSubDetails='["tweets", "followers", "following"]'
     rightSubDetails='["follow", "reply", "addList"]'
}}
{{/view-users}}
```